# How to make excel stop treating column as date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

My column values are as follows:

```
1-1
1-2
2-1
2-2
...
12-1
12-2
13-1
13-2
...
n-1
n-2
```

On cells containing 1-1 up to 12-2, excel doesn't meddle with me, but starting on 13-1 up to the nth row, it shows warning "**Text date with 2-digit year**". Unfortunately, this are really not dates. Also, I already tried formatting the said rows/cells as **text** before inputting any values, but really when excel sees "13-1" and above, it shows the error. How should I fix this?

Additional info: when the rows are shown using formula, there are no errors, but sadly, using formula is not an option and I need values as is.

Comment: What do you mean **exactly** by *'before inputting any values'* ? If this an import then the text conversion needs to be done there; if you are typing values in then setting the column to text beforehand should have been sufficient.

Comment: @Jeeped I either **type text**, or **copy+paste values**, but it doesn't work. (1) I created a new workbook just now, (2) then formatted some cells to _text_, (3) then finally typed to one of those cells "13-1" - the error showed up immediately.

Comment: @ShawnMogensen please select any answer to appreciate there effort

Comment: **Related news**:  [Scientists rename human genes to stop Microsoft Excel from misreading them as dates](https://www.theverge.com/platform/amp/2020/8/6/21355674/human-genes-rename-microsoft-excel-misreading-dates) ... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can type ="1-1" instead of just 1-1
When you type 1-1, excel change this to 1-Jan. When you type ="1-1" , Excel treat the value as string. Hope it helps.

Comment: Typically, `'1-1` is more commonly used.

Comment: I tried this with a newly created worksheet, I've uploaded it in [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=67718800961253833126).

Comment: @ShawnMogensen When you type ="12-1" excel treat first number (12) as month and second number(1) as date so it changes to 1-Dec. You typed ="13-1" and hence 13 is not a month number it just display as 13-1 and it works fine.

Comment: I think using the format ="1-1" or '1-1 should work fine, but I tried it by even using a newly created workbook, but it **still** shows the error. What maybe the causes of this?

Comment: @ShawnMogensen which version if excel are u working in?

Comment: @user9422872 I'm using Office 2013 Pro. Plus.

Comment: @ShawnMogensen It works fine in office 2007. I m still using office 2007. Lol.

Comment: @user9422872 Unfortunately I don't have office 2007. Anyways, have you checked the file I've uploaded? I tried in there the different formattings suggested, placed in row 1.

Answer (score 3):

Just right click on the column click on Format Cells ... on Number Tab on Category List select Text, this will make anything you enter or have as a text.

But if you are copy paste data then use Match Destination Format (M), just right click on the cell and select Match Destination Format (M) not Ctrl-V.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a  single quote to the start of the dates Excel treats it as a string. Works for numbers as text too

Answer (score 1):

**Stop excel from converting copy-pasted number/text values to date**

1. Copy the original data
2. Paste to Notepad / Notepad++
3. In Excel, change the Format Cells / Number Format (that shows "General" as default) to TEXT
4. Copy your data from Notepad
5. Paste back **to the Excel cells, in which you have changed the format to TEXT**

Answer (score 0):

Turn off error checks for those types of errors.

```
With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
    .TextDate = False
    .NumberAsText = False
End With
```

Also found within File, Options, Formulas, Error checking rules.